# c++- _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) error?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to create a 2D game. Currently I am trying to kill an enemy when it touches my player. However when the enemy and player collide my program aborts and I get the error _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse).
What am I doing wrong?
update function detecting collision in enemy class:

```
void Enemy::update(Player& player){

    Normalised.x = (player.pos.x - vec.x) / vec.distanceSquared(player.pos);
    Normalised.y = (player.pos.y - vec.y) / vec.distanceSquared(player.pos);

    if (vec.distanceSquared(player.pos)<0.5){
        vec.x += Normalised.x*zombie_speed;
        vec.y += Normalised.y*zombie_speed;
    }

    if (player.radius + radius>(vec.distance(player.pos))){
        alive = false;
    }
};
```

Then in my main.cpp I declare

```
Enemy enemy1(0.9,0.9,0.2);
Enemy enemy2(0.4, 0.4, 0.2);
vector<Enemy*> enemyList;
```

Then I put my enemies into the vector in a init() function in main.cpp

```
enemyList.push_back(&enemy1);
enemyList.push_back(&enemy2);
```

And this is where I do the check in main.cpp in an update function to see if an enemy is alive, if not then delete (kill) it...

```
vector<Enemy*>::iterator ie;
    for (ie = enemyList.begin(); ie != enemyList.end(); ie++) {
        if ((*ie)->alive==false){
        delete *ie;
        enemyList.erase(ie);
    }
}
```

Comment: `enemyList.erase(ie);` invalidates `ie` and you then try to increment it. Use the erase remove idiom instead.

Comment: I am not familiar with that, sorry I am quite new to c++. How could I implement that? Thanks your help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove will "remove" things from a vector by shifting the elements after them backward, but WITHOUT resizing the vector--so your "ie" iterator will remain valid.  If you used that within your loop then you would need to stop at the new end-iterator (returned by std::remove) rather than at enemyList.end(), AND not increment ie on an iteration where a deletion happened, AND resize the vector after the loop ended to finally, truly remove the bad elements (which std::remove will have put at its end).  I think.

Comment: Another strategy would be to use std::stable_sort to put items with alive==false at the end of the vector, and then call pop_back() on the vector until (enemyList.empty() || enemyList.back()->alive) was true.  Another would be to loop as you are currently doing, but add living enemies to a new vector instead of removing them from the old, and then call .swap() on one of the vectors to exchange the two.

Comment: Oh hm apparently erase() returns a "next iterator" value that you can use to resume iteration.  So you could maybe do like "for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end();) if (v->gotKilled()) i = v.erase(i); else ++i;"  Sorry for all the comments; apparently I am interested enough to babble at length yet too lazy to fully verify all this stuff myself and post it as a formal answer